# javascript : I could delete the property form object, the property, which is defined as non configurable. Why?

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj={};
Object.defineProperty(obj,'test',{value:300,configurable:false});
console.log(obj.test)
delete obj.test
console.log(obj)
```

'test' property defined as non-configurable can be deleted. But as per my knowledge it should not. Could some please explain why this is happening.

Comment: Running this code in Firefox's console, the object is unchanged.

Comment: ^ Same in Chrome's console.

Answer (score 5):

If you had logged `obj.test` instead of just `obj`, you'd have noticed that the property is still there and not actually deleted. You have to set `enumerable: true` in order for the property to show up when logging the object's properties (i.e. the object itself). It's set to `false` by default.

**Logging `obj.test` with the default, `enumerable: false`:**

```js
var obj={};
Object.defineProperty(obj,'test',{value:300,configurable:false});
console.log(obj.test)
delete obj.test
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.test)
```

**Logging `obj.test` with `enumerable: true`:**

```js
var obj={};
Object.defineProperty(obj,'test',{value:300,configurable:false,enumerable:true});
console.log(obj.test)
delete obj.test
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: nice one! But how did the consoles in browsers know to still log it even without enumerable? any idea?

Comment: A bit of a misleading issue, as this custom console implementation used by stack snippets causes the `test` property not to show, since it's not `enumerable`. Chrome and Firefox can log the entry just fine.

Comment: In Firefox, you'll actually notice a small difference: With `enumerable: false`, it will log `Object { ... }` and you'll have to manually expand it, while `enumerable: true` will log `Object { test: 300 }` directly.

Comment: Nice! tnx for the clarification guys :D

Comment: I have just consoled obj.test after deletion of test from object in my case above. It is given undefined.

Comment: You can verify that it's still set, executing the first snippet in my answer. If it doesn't work for you, please tell us what browser you are using. It might be an implementation issue then.

Comment: Yes, still same issue. My Browser is Google chrome 
Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: So you are executing my snippet, and instead of `300` in the last line it is loggin `undefined` for you? if that'sthe case, I'm a bit baffled as to what is going on, as I'm using the exact same version of Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes, it is, I can give screenshot of the same, but I don't know where to attach here. Just to add when run the same code using node, it is showing correct output.

Comment: You could post the screenshot to a free image hosting service and link to it here.